# Archiving old websites with StormCrawler and Elasticsearch

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

when storm crawler re-visits a website which has already been fetched before, it updates the corresponding document in the elasticsearch index. I.e., the old content is overwritten by the new one.

Is there any stormcrawler functionality which allows us to keep the old version of certain fields and annotate it with a timestamp?

We looked into the elasticsearch rollover api and ingest pipelines. The ingest pipelines look promising to modify elasticsearch documents on update operations. Is there any way to append the pipeline parameter (i.e., ?pipeline=xxx) via the stormcrawler configuration to relevant elasticsearch requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to use the URL + timestamp as key and store each version of the document separately. You'd have to deduplicate at search time though. This would need a minor change to the code.

We can't currently append params via the config, but it should be doable. I never used the pipelines in ES, can't they be configured to be used by default on a particular index?

Comment: Default pipelines on indices are currently discussed on github (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21101) but not implemented/released yet.

Comment: see https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/584
will try to have a look at it soon

Comment: There's also a setPipeline method on the request object - we could add a config to use it in the indexer
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-index.html

Comment: Have pushed a commit for the issue above. @s_f could you please give it a try and let me know if it works?

Comment: i changed the pom entries to 1.10 and run mvn clean package, but get a maven error that the 1.10 stormcrawler and elasticsearch dependencies cannot be found

Comment: I'm in the process of finishing the release and it will take a few hours before the artefacts are synched to maven central. I meant that you could test it by checking out storm-crawler from the master branch and build it yourself

Comment: works really good. with ingest support it is now possible to easily enrich/modify the crawling data in elasticsearch. thanks for the fast support.